# powershell how to pipeline FOR loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update a array with a for loop like this

```
$comps = Get-ChildItem $LocalPath -recurse | Select-String -pattern "MyStringFilter" | group path | select name | Foreach {"$($_.Name)".substring(0,"$($_.Name)".IndexOf('.')).substring("$($_.Name)".LastIndexOf('\')+1) }
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $comps.count; $i++) {
  if ($comps[$i].substring(0,3) -eq "AAA") {$comps[$i] = "/aaa "+$comps[$i]}  else {$comps[$i] = "/bbb "+$comps[$i]}
}
$comps
```

The above code works fine but when I try to make it into a pipeline using forEach the array variable becomes empty.

```
$comps = Get-ChildItem $LocalPath -recurse | Select-String -pattern "MyStringFilter" | group path | select name | Foreach {$_.Name.substring(0,$_.Name.IndexOf('.')).substring($_.Name.LastIndexOf('\')+1) } | foreach { if ($_.substring(0,3) -eq "AAA" ) {$_ = "/aaa "+$_} else {$_ = "/bbb "+$_} }
```

What have I missed? Any way to make it work?

thanks,

Comment: `{"/aaa "+$_} else {"/bbb "+$_}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to the iteration value `$_` inside `ForEach-Object`'s block:

```
$comps = Get-ChildItem $LocalPath -recurse | Select-String -pattern "MyStringFilter" | group path | select name | Foreach {
    $_.Name.substring(0,$_.Name.IndexOf('.')).substring($_.Name.LastIndexOf('\')+1) 
} | foreach { 
    if ($_.substring(0,3) -eq "AAA" ) {
        "/aaa "+$_
    } else {
        "/bbb "+$_
    } 
}
```

Instead, do as above and let the value you want to assign be the return value of the block. All of the returns from each iteration make up an array, and the assignment happens all the way at the beginning of that statement when you do `$comps =`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Appreciate it.